# I think i need to create custom layout but i don't know how to do it

Tags: java, android

i want to design this
[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwTby.jpg)

and this is what i get after hitting API you can see the difference between the items that's why its not looking cool i used grid layout in recycler view give 3 to it that's why if the words length increased its increased the item height 
[this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fVCs.jpg)

and this is my code

```
public void apiCalling() {
 APIinterface apIinterface = 

APIClient.getClient().create(APIinterface.class);
retrofit2.Call<WatchListModel> call = apIinterface.getWatchListModel();

call.enqueue(new Callback<WatchListModel>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<WatchListModel> call, 
Response<WatchListModel> response) {

ArrayList<Object> alldata = (ArrayList<Object>) 
response.body().getWishlist().get(0).getBlogTags();
Log.e("alldata", "onBindViewHolder: " + alldata);
for (int c = 0; c <= alldata.size() - 1; c++) {
String Blogtag = String.valueOf(alldata.get(c));
blogarray.add(Blogtag);
Log.e("blogtag", " " + blogarray);
}
List<Wishlist> wishlist = response.body().getWishlist();
detail.setText(wishlist.get(0).getBlogDescription());
Log.e("witchlist", "onResponse: " + wishlist);
watchlist_recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 
3));
watchListAdapter = new WatchListAdapter(lorem, wishlist, blogarray);
watchlist_recycler.setAdapter(watchListAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<WatchListModel> call, Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Check your internet n=connection", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
});
}`
```

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful.